# How to sort by number in data validation

Tags: sorting, validation, google-sheets, dropdown, string-formatting

I have currently a problem where I am trying to filter based on numbers that I have put on in data validation:

[image: Data validation]

As you can see the numbers goes from 1 to 11 and when I am using the filter to sort A-Z, it goes by 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...

[image: 1-10]

and I wonder how can I filter it by going numberic? meaning 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way would be to use `01` prefix instead of `1`

this would then sort:

```
01
02
10
11
```

Comment: That was smart! and worked as I wanted too aswell! Apprecaite it!